# Do electrostatic forces affect the induced EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, conductors

Let's say we have a **linear conductor** which is slipping with a **constant velocity** in a **static magnetic field** perpendicular to the plane defined by the axis and the velocity of the conductor. Due to the accumulation of the charge at its edges, an electrostatic field is developed. Are we taking this field into account when we calculate the induced EMF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrostatic field is not part of induced or motional EMF.

EMF due to motion of the conductor in magnetic field is called *motional EMF*. It is present whether the charges are accumulated at the endpoints or not - it is due to action of magnetic forces and internal constraint forces in the conductor.

Due to presence of magnetic field, the conductor is doing some work on those charges to move them to a state of higher elecric potential energy and as a result, not acquiring as much kinetic energy as it would in the absence of magnetic field.

This process or rearrangement starts due to change of speed of the conductor. It takes some (very short) time until the new charge distribution is established. So the electrostatic field is established *due to* motional EMF, it is not part of it.

Comment: Thank you very much! But what happens in the case that the conductor is slipping without frictions on the two conducting rails of a closed circuit. I'm thinking that there is an electrostatic force (F=qE) which is generated by the repulsive forces between charges in the whole circuit. Do we take it into account for the EMF calculation?

Comment: There is electrostatic field if the conductor is moving, but it does not change EMF, because EMF is a different concept. In this case, EMF is acting on the charge carriers in opposite direction to electrostatic forces.